# PostgreSQL recursive with

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

I need help with a recursive query. Assuming the following table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tree (
    id        integer PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id integer NOT NULL,
    name      varchar(50)
);    

INSERT INTO tree (id, parent_id, name) VALUES (3, 0, 'Peter'), (2,0, 'Thomas'), (5,2, 'David'), (1, 0, 'Rob'), (8, 0, 'Brian');
```

I can retrieve a list of all people and their children with the following query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursetree(id, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id FROM tree WHERE parent_id = 0
  UNION
    SELECT t.id, t.parent_id
    FROM tree t
    JOIN recursetree rt ON rt.id = t.parent_id
  )
SELECT * FROM recursetree;
```

How can I list them in order, and also sort the first level items by name? For example, the desired output would be:

```
id, parent_id, name    
8, 0, "Brian"
3, 0, "Peter"
1, 0; "Rob"
2, 0, "Thomas"
5, 2, "  David"
```

Thanks,

**EDIT. Please note that adding an ORDER BY won't work: **

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursetree(id, parent_id, path, name) AS (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        parent_id, 
        array[id] AS path, 
        name 
    FROM tree WHERE parent_id = 0
  UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, rt.path || t.id, t.name
    FROM tree t
    JOIN recursetree rt ON rt.id = t.parent_id
  )
SELECT * FROM recursetree ORDER BY path;
```

The above will retain the parent child relationship (children follow their parents), but applying any other ORDER BY clause (ie: name - like some have suggested) will cause the result to lose it's parent-child relationships.

Comment: Isn't a simple ORDERBY doing the trick?

Comment: An ORDER BY wouldn't place children under their parents, only order everything by name.

Answer (score 7):

See also this (translated) article about CTE's in PostgreSQL: [wiki.phpfreakz.nl](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?hl=nl&ie=UTF-8&sl=nl&tl=en&u=http://wiki.phpfreakz.nl/CommonTableExpression&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&usg=ALkJrhgDErtL5I_yWE3-o75N-dLj7GLN7Q)

Edit: Try this one, using an array:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursetree(id, parent_ids, firstname) AS (
    SELECT id, NULL::int[] || parent_id, name FROM tree WHERE parent_id = 0
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    t.id, 
    rt.parent_ids || t.parent_id, 
    name
    FROM tree t
    JOIN recursetree rt ON rt.id = t.parent_id
  )
SELECT * FROM recursetree ORDER BY parent_ids;
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, the crux of the problem remains - I have to sort by path to retain ordering, but I need to sort top-level items by a field (in this case name).

Comment: Just use an array in the CTE, a child will always have more elements in the array as it's parents, an ASCending order will do the trick.

Comment: probably "ORDER BY parent_ids, firstname" to order the top-level items by name as well (which will all have {0} as their parent_ids)

Comment: Frank, I'm not sure what you're suggesting. Are you suggesting storing the path in an array? If so, I still need to sort on that field to retain relationships - which means I won't be able to sort on name. See my edit above.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible to sort on name? It works fine over here. Show us a case that doesn't work. (ps. 0 is an incorrect parent_id, it does not exist. You'd better use NULL when is there is no parent)

Comment: WITH RECURSIVE recursetree(id, parent_id, name) AS (
    SELECT id, NULL::int[] || parent_id, name FROM tree WHERE parent_id = 0
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    t.id, rt.parent_id || t.parent_id, t.name
    FROM tree t
    JOIN recursetree rt ON rt.id = t.parent_id
  )
SELECT * FROM recursetree ORDER BY name;

Comment: Apologies for the formatting above. The above query orders by name - as a result children no longer follow their parents in the result.

Comment: Ofcourse not! Why should it? You don't order by parent, why would the database order by something you don't tell it to do so? ORDER BY parent_ids, name;

Comment: Thanks Frank. I appreciate the help, but that still wont work. Because you're ordering on path first, you're going to be ordering by id - not name.

Comment: I think it may be easier (although less efficient) to do a last sort in the application logic to order the results correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a path to your query and order by it at the end:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursetree(id, parent_id,path) AS (
  SELECT id, parent_id,id||'' as path FROM tree WHERE parent_id = 0
UNION
  SELECT t.id, t.parent_id,concat(rt.path,'_',t.id)
  FROM tree t
  JOIN recursetree rt ON rt.id = t.parent_id
) 
SELECT * FROM recursetree
ORDER BY rt.path;
```